# Mongodb $group and $lookup aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two Collections `Upload` and `Notification` and I want to `populate` `imageid` of `Notification` with `_id` of `Upload` Collection. However `$lookup` returns an empty array

```
const user = req.user.id;

    const aggregation = await Notification.aggregate(

        [
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: { imageid: '$imageid' },
                    to_userid: { $first: user },
                    opened: { $first: '$opened' },
                    imageid: { $first: '$imageid' },
                    notification_date: { $first: '$notification_date' },
                    total: { $sum: 1 }
                }
            },

            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "Upload",
                    localField: "imageid",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "images"
                }
            },
        ]
   )
```

Comment: This question will have more info with sample docs ! Please edit..And also it's not `two Documents` it's `two Collections`

Comment: do you mean document model?

Comment: no actual docs & required o/p can help a lot to better understand

Comment: @whoami can you please check , ive edited the question

Comment: Ok I missed this above comment, I've asked for sample documents to check types of the fields !! There is a reason why we're asking for those.. Anyhow on a blind guess I would say you might be comparing string(imageid) to type ObjectId()(_id) can you check if that's the case or not !!